# Não consigo mudar backgroundcolor usando javascript para gerar cores aleatorias

Tags: javascript, random, hexadecimal

```js
// randomColor() funcionando perfeitamente, gerando codigos hex entre ""
function randomColor() {
  const hex = (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
  return `"#${hex}"`;
}
/* Em teoria deveria estar funcionando, quando eu troco o return do randomColor
para "red" ou "blue" funciona */

function randomButton(){
  let x = randomColor()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="randomButton()" value="Mudar cor">
```

Answer (score 1):

É só retornar a sua cor, sem as aspas ao redor dela, veja:

```js
 // randomColor() funcionando perfeitamente, gerando codigos hex entre ""
  function randomColor() {
    const hex = (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    return `#${hex}`;
  }
  /* Em teoria deveria estar funcionando, quando eu troco o return do randomColor
  para "red" ou "blue" funciona */

  function randomButton(){
  let x = randomColor()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="randomButton()" value="Mudar cor">
```